# PHP check text is in English language?

Tags: php, regex

Hello everyone below is given code I want to test string is in English or in Gujarati. But program giving wrong output how can I solve this? If the character is ASCII is from 0A80-0AFF this length then considers as Gujarati else consider as English.

Code:

```
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $Query)){
    echo 'English';
}
else{
    echo 'Gujarati';
}
```

Input:

```
A/4
```

Output:

```
Gujarati
```

Expected output:

```
English
```

Comment: Since you're only checking against alphanumeric characters, any input containing anything else (like slashes/hyphens etc) will be considered to be Gujarati.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Absolutely correct How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a case where you have only, **English** and **Gujarati**, why don't you do it the other way around?

```
if (preg_match('/\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}/u', $Query)){
    echo 'Gujarati';
}
else{
    echo 'English';
}
```

Basically if you have one character from **Gujarati** language it will be detected as `Gujarati` else it will be `English`. However note that `月`,`ありがとう`, `élève`, etc will also be considered as **English**

Have a look at this Unicode chart: https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0A80.pdf to define exactly the range that must be taken into account.

**Explanations**:

1. `\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}` to match characters between code points `U+0A80` and `U+0AFF`
2. `/u` for Unicode support in regex

Comment: I want the same solution but it covers 0A80-0AFF range? So I can use it.

Comment: @ShahRushabh:  I have edited the regex to match your range can you have a look?

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my project.

Comment: @ShahRushabh: Happy to help you ;-)

Comment: Allan, is this correct range syntax? '/\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}/u'. Not this? '/[\x{0A80}-\x{0AFF}]/u'

Comment: @A.Denis I am not an expert of Gujarati language that's why I gave him the Unicode chart for Gujarati language, he can adapt the regex if necessary

Comment: @Allan I am asking about that you don't use those square brackets. I always think that brackets must be.

Comment: please check this, function is_english($str)
{
 if (strlen($str) != strlen(utf8_decode($str))) {
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }